# awk Command Loop

Tags: awk

```
awk '{print $1 ,": "  $3}' Src.txt | column -t
awk '{for(x=2;$x;++x) print $1, $x "\n"}'  Src.txt | column -t
```

These commands are working but formatting is not proper either I can only print column one and column two or I can print column 1 followd by column 2 and column 3 but the desired result is

```
column 1 column 2
column 1 column 3
column 1 column 4 .....
```

Example :

```
Col1  a b c
Col2  1 2 3  
col3  x y z
```

Output

```
Col1 a
Col2 b
Col3 c

Col1 b
col2 2
Col3 y

Col1 c
Col2 3
Col3 z
```

Maybe need to add proper looping?

Comment: Need more info. What is in Src.txt?

Comment: There is no logic in your example, I believe you meant in first group `Col1 a` `Col2 1` `Col3 x`.

Comment: @Mel thats the source file name

Comment: @arsh what is inside the Src.txt - can you show the results of `head Src.txt`

Answer (score 3):

The way awk works is that by default it steps through each *line* of text and splits every space-separated item into fields, in this case we have fields $2, $3,and $4 of interest. Now what if we could store each $2 field of each line into a list and then print it ?  That's where arrays can help.

Treating the body of an awk code as one big while loop, we can separate fields 2,3,and 4 into appropriate arrays. With each line, arrays will get filled. So we basically sort everything into columns(arrays) as we go though lines. Once done, we can go through a loop printing each colum(array) separately, while just adding text "Column#".

```
$ awk '{ array1[NR]=$2;array2[NR]=$3;array3[NR]=$4} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){print "Column"i" "array1[i]};printf "\n";for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){print "Column"i" "array2[i]}; printf"\n"; for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){print "Column"i" "array3[i] };printf "\n" }' columns.txt           
Column1 a
Column2 1
Column3 x

Column1 b
Column2 2
Column3 y

Column1 c
Column2 3
Column3 z
```

Of course that one long line is a bit awkward to use (no awk puns intended). We can put everything into a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ array1[NR]=$2;array2[NR]=$3;array3[NR]=$4 } 

END{
  for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){
     print "Column"i" "array1[i]};printf "\n";
   for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){
     print "Column"i" "array2[i]}; printf"\n"; 
   for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){
     print "Column"i" "array3[i] };printf "\n" 
}
```

Call that script `columnate.awk`, change permissions to executable with `chmod +x columnate.awk` and run it with any text file as a parameter:

```
$ ./columnate.awk columns.txt                                                                                                                          
Column1 a
Column2 1
Column3 x

Column1 b
Column2 2
Column3 y

Column1 c
Column2 3
Column3 z
```

Comment: Hi Serg, I am getting the following error when I am running the script, I am running it on kash. $ sh awktest.sh Src.txt
awktest.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
awktest.sh: line 7: `  for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)'
Please advise

Comment: @arsh The way you run it is `sh awktest.sh Src.txt`. The way you should run it is as like I show in my example. `./awktest.sh Src.txt` . There is already a `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`, that's what will determine how to run the script.  Alternatively if you insist on using sh , you can do `sh -c 'awktest.sh Src.txt'` . By the way, just a curiosity, you said you're running that with kash. Did you mean ksh or is it some new shell kash ?

Comment: By the way, small note, ./ means to run script that is in current directory. So if your script is located in Documents folder, navigate there with `cd ~/Documents` and do the ./

Comment: it worked thank you soooo much for your help. its ksh sorry about the typo, also i need to replace the columns with the real header names and auto this for example if there are three rows or data value it should only print 3 if there are 4 rows data values it should only print 4 now i am getting and additional box ...

Comment: i got the below result  Column1 410192,
Column2 2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000,
Column3 MySource,
Column4 123456,
Column5 VALIDATION_FAILED_MILESTONE,
Column6 2015-06-11T02:18:40+0000

Column1 410182,
Column2 2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000,
Column3 jmeter-LR04,
Column4 PASSLR04,
Column5 VALIDATION_FAILED_MILESTONE,
Column6 2015-06-11T02:12:28+0000

Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5
Column6

Comment: @arsh could you please that to paste.ubuntu.com ? or pastebin ? It's a bit hard to read everything in the comments since there is no formating here. Also, it's always better to use actual input values in the question, instead of a,b,c, because we need to adjust for space and special characters

Comment: i have copied it to http://paste.ubuntu.com/11801108/ ...Please let me know...

Comment: @arsh OK, I see comas added at the end of each item. Is your text file has everything coma-separated ? Can you provide me with a sample text to operate on ?

Comment: I think I have an idea how to fix the actual headers. We can place everything into another array

Comment: yea everything is going to be comma separated, How can i send you an actual file ... i have posted the actual file on ubuntu

Comment: @arsh Just paste it to paste.ubuntu.com and copy the link here into the comments. Is there anything else I should know about the file ?